# How can I install boost-devel in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: compiling, boost, flv, scons

I want to compile flvtool++, but it requires boost-devel libraries.

I tried to install it via this command:

```
sudo apt-get install boost-devel
```

But I got the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package boost-devel
```

Is there an other way to compile flvtool++ source or any 64-bit binaries?

Comment: I think you should install libboost-dev

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu ... development packages end with a -dev extension unlike the -devel extension found in .rpm systems.Btw,you should use synaptic when you are unsure about the correct package name (or muon on qt systems).

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 16):

To develop with the Boost libraries in Ubuntu/Debian, you need to install the *libboost-all-dev* package:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: are debug symbols included in this package?