# How to install Boost 1.60 on 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, boost

I am trying to work out how to install Boost 1.60 under Travis CI, which runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server Edition 64-bit.

I tried adding the `debian-sid` repo as an apt source so I could install `libboost-program-options1.60-dev` but this fails with [a bunch of errors](https://travis-ci.org/Malvineous/libgamearchive/jobs/128457583) which appear to be caused by a Debian package being incompatible with Ubuntu.

So it looks like the solution is to find a Ubuntu package for Boost 1.60, however not being very familiar with Ubuntu, I am struggling with this.  If I go to Launchpad and do a search then I can only find [one mention of Boost 1.60](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/boost1.60) but I am unclear whether this can be installed in 12.04 and how it could be done.

I am using containers in Travis CI so `sudo` is not available, which rules out installing a `.deb` file directly.  All I can do is add APT sources and then install packages from that source, if they are whitelisted (or apply to have them whitelisted.)

I did find the [boost-latest](https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest) PPA but despite the name this contains only very old versions of Boost, so it unfortunately doesn't appear to be kept up to date - apparently due to some disagreement with Canonical.

So I'm a little stuck!  Does anyone know whether it's possible to get Boost 1.60 under Ubuntu LTS 12.04?

*Note: This is not a duplicate of [163976](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163976/how-can-i-install-boost-devel-in-ubuntu-12-04) - that question is about any Boost version, but I am specifically after 1.60 as the latest stable version is too old.*

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @aggsol: No I had to build it from source.  There are PPAs where it seems to be available but trying to get them set up was more trouble than it was worth.